# Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Prove that $f(x-y)g(y)$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

This is a problem that appears in Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis text. Below are some  results relevant to this problem that appear elsewhere in the text, stated exactly as they're written there.

**Corollary 3.7** : *Suppose $f$ is a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then the function $f$ defined by $\tilde{f}(x,y) = f(x)$* is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{d_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d_2}$.

**Proposition 3.9** : *If $f$ is a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$, then the function $\tilde{f}(x,y) = f(x-y)$* is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$.

**Property 5 (ii)** : If $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then $f + g$ and $fg$ are measurable if both $f$ and $g$ are finite-valued.

**Remark on Property 5 (ii)** : Property 5 (ii) also holds when $f$ and $g$ are finite-valued almost everywhere.

By Corollary 3.7, both $\tilde{f}(x,y) = f(x)$ and $\tilde{g}(x,y) = g(y)$ are measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d = \mathbb{R}^{2d}$. By Proposition 3.9, the function $\tilde{\tilde{{f}}}(x,y) = f(x-y)$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$.

We have that $f(x-y)$ and $g(y)$ are each measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$. It remains to show that their product is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$, and this is where my question comes in.

By Property 5 (ii) and the remark that follows, the product of two measurable functions is not, in general, measurable ; we need to know that $f(x-y)$ and $g(y)$ are each either finite-valued or finite-valued almost everywhere. However, in the statement of the problem, the only information that we're given is $f$ and $g$ are measurable on $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$. In general, measurable functions are not finite-valued or finite-valued almost everywhere.

Am I missing something ? Is there an underlying assumption about $f$ and $g$ that I'm not paying attention to ? How can I show that $f$ and $g$ are each either finite-valued or finite-valued almost everywhere to complete the proof ?

Thanks !

Comment: I feel like something is missing here. The product $f(x-y)g(y)$ doesn't even necessarily make sense; what happens if $f$ is constant $\infty$ and $g$ is constant $-\infty$?

Comment: @Thorgott This was another thought of mine, as well. I wonder what was intended by the authors as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address the comment, we could define $(-\infty)(\infty)=-\infty$, which I'm sure is the usual convention. Also, $0\times \infty = 0\times (-\infty)=0$ and so on. The only issues with arithmetic are things like $\frac{1}{\infty}$, $\frac{1}{0}$ and $\infty-\infty$. As long as we avoid these things, everything else works "nicely".

Property 5(ii) can be generalized as  follows:

- Let $f,g:\Bbb{R}^d\to [-\infty,\infty]$ be (Lebesgue) measurable. (Actually the domain can be any measure space, but if I recall correctly, Stein and Shakarchi don't get to this until later on). Then, $fg$ is (Lebesgue) measurable. Furthermore, if the sum $f+g$ is well-defined (i.e for every $x\in \Bbb{R}^d$, we have $(f(x),g(x))\notin \{(\infty, -\infty), (-\infty, \infty)\}$), then $f+g$ is also Lebesgue measurable.

The proof of course will have to be different. For instance we could proceed directly. Recall the following equivalences for measurability of a function $f:\Bbb{R}^d\to [-\infty,\infty]$:

- For every Borel (or even open) set $V\subset [-\infty,\infty]$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is measurable.
- For every Borel (or even open) set $U\subset \Bbb{R}$, the sets $\{f=\infty\}, \{f=-\infty\}$ and $f^{-1}(U)$ are measurable.

So, for the case of the product, we have:
\begin{align}
\{fg=\infty\} &= \bigg(\{f=\infty\}\cap\{0< g\leq \infty\}\bigg) \cup\bigg(\{f=-\infty\}\cap  \{-\infty \leq g < 0\}\bigg)\\
& \cup \bigg(\{g=\infty\}\cap\{0< f\leq \infty\}\bigg) \cup\bigg(\{g=-\infty\}\cap  \{-\infty \leq f < 0\}\bigg)
\end{align}
Each of the eight sets on the right is measurable because $f$ and $g$ are. These are all basic set operations hence $\{fg=\infty\}$ is also measurable. Similar reasoning holds for $\{fg=-\infty\}$. To finish the proof, we need to show that for every Borel $U\subset \Bbb{R}$, the set $(fg)^{-1}(U)$ is measurable; but this follows from the finite version.

Indeed, let $\phi=f$ whenever $f$ is finite, and $0$ elsewhere. Define $\gamma$ in terms of $g$ similarly. Then, $\phi, \gamma$ are measurable because $f$ and $g$ are. Then, for every Borel set $U\subset \Bbb{R}$, we have
\begin{align}
(fg)^{-1}(U) &= (fg)^{-1}(U\setminus \{0\}) \cup (fg)^{-1}(0)\\
&= (\phi\gamma)^{-1}(U\setminus \{0\})\cup f^{-1}(0)\cup g^{-1}(0)
\end{align}
This is a union of measurable sets hence measurable. This completes the proof that $fg$ is measurable.

---

Essentially it's just a bit of more case work, but apart from that the result is true. Thus, $(x,y)\mapsto f(x-y)g(y)$ is also measurable.